Computer possesses a woman on a chair that rises up
For many years I have had recurring memories of a film/episode of something about a computer that takes over a woman. I think it was from the 80's or 90's.
What I remember is: 
A team of people enter an old bunker of some sort, discovering some kind of old dusty lair. In a central chamber they find a chair which is seemingly also a computer. The woman sits in the chair and the bunker powers up. She is immediately possessed. As the people try to communicate with her, she always refers to herself in the third person, by the name of the computer. 
I also remember that the entire chair, woman and all, is connected to some sort of platform that will elevate after some time, and the people are trying to prevent this. 
Some men dressed in suits, though not men in black, show up as well and try to reason with the computer. I have a vague recollection that this is the computer's doing, as these people were dead, and the computer is controlling time. 
She/the computer starts to elevate towards the surface, cogs lifting her upwards, as the reasoning failed.

Is this animated or live action, and what language?

First thing I thought of was Superman III.  That doesn't fit the details beyond 'Computer takes over woman'.

Ingve, if you're still around, I found a pretty good match from the 1991 British sci-fi show Dark Season that starred a young Kate Winslet in her first major role. It's about students discovering a sinister plot that involves computers possessing humans. Here's what happens in the second half of this 6-episode series when an archaeologist called Miss Pendragon and her team uncover an underground room:

Pendragon finds the installation’s control room and reactivates the Behemoth – in fact a powerful defence computer that she created, but which was abandoned when the government learn of her fascist beliefs. Pendragon tells Thomas that the systems need a final, human, component – a ‘chosen one’ – which is to be him; but Thomas objects and pushes Pendragon into the control chair – metal clamps pin the woman in place and the Behemoth’s systems awaken. Under Pendragon’s control, the machine rises up through the earth, bursting through the ground and emerging in the school assembly hall...

Behemoth absorbs Pendragon's mind and refers to her in the third person before starting to rise:

A man in a suit then appears, and it turns out to be the villain, Mr. Eldrich, who can control Behemoth and wants it to destroy the world:

But Protagonist Marcie then tries to reason with the computer and convince it not to destroy the world. The entire series is available in parts on Youtube; you can see Behemoth rising in Episode 5 here.

Is it the 1977 Julie Christie film "Demon Seed"? 

Could you elaborate?
